# I want to only the contents of directories and his subdirectories to a directory without copying the directory and subdirectory

Tags: linux

**INPUT:-**

I have one directory that contain sub directories as well and sub directories also contain some data like this.

test/abc/def/file1.txt

test/abc/file2.txt

test/file3.txt

And i need all the files in one directory like this

Means i need all the data from sub directories to one folder

**OUTPUT:-**

test2/file1.txt

test2/file2.txt

test2/file3.txt

Comment: What if there are duplicate filenames?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find all files:

   ```
   find source/ -type f
   ```
2. Copy multiple files to a single directory:

   ```
   cp -t target/ files...
   ```
3. Combine both commands:

   ```
   find source/ -type f -exec cp -t target/ '{}' +
   ```
4. Profit